# The editor doesn't correctly build the link when the selected text contains brackets

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

The button to create a link doesn't behave correctly when the text contains brackets.

Suppose you want to create a link from "unicorns -[discussion]"; selecting the text, and clicking the link button produces the following output: [unicorns -[discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicorns%20-%5Bdiscussion%5D)].

The brackets surround the selected text, but the "`[1]`" part is inside those brackets, and not outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=0d90f393123b2b9567f23567d7e512ec4efd4420) and [there](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=d947e2b1ba7bacd02b18e885cea57eb8226f2943) ya go (this is in the next build).

Note that the case of *removing* a link with the button may still not work quite correctly with brackets in certain cases. Since that's not such a huge issue (as the button is usually used to *create* links) and anything but trivial (given the way the editor implements this), I'm okay with that for now.

But when *creating* links via the button, any unescaped brackets are now escaped in the link text, so they don't break the link.

Comment: This was quick. `:-)` I agree, the bigger issue was adding links though the button. I think it's rare to remove a link with the button.